# UICollectionView OrthogonalScrollingBehavior make sticky header disappear

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm trying to make collectionView with CompositionalLayout, and make certain cell always stay sticky to the top whether the other section appears or not.
Here is my code customizing UICollectionViewLayout

```
public final class StickyCollectionViewCompositionalLayout: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    var stickyIndexPath: IndexPath? {
        didSet {
            invalidateLayout()
        }
    }
    
    init(
        stickyIndexPath: IndexPath?,
        configuration: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration,
        sectionProvider: @escaping UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutSectionProvider
    ) {
        self.stickyIndexPath = stickyIndexPath
        super.init(sectionProvider: sectionProvider, configuration: configuration)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // 스크롤 할 때마다 layout 재설정
    public override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    public override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        
        if let stickyAttributes = getStickyAttributes(at: stickyIndexPath) {
            layoutAttributes?.append(stickyAttributes)
        }
        
        return layoutAttributes
    }
    
    private func getStickyAttributes(at indexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        guard
            let collectionView = self.collectionView,
            let indexPath = indexPath,
            let stickyAttributes = layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)?.copy()
                as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        else {
            return nil
        }
        
        if collectionView.contentOffset.y > stickyAttributes.frame.minY {
            var frame = stickyAttributes.frame
            frame.origin.y = collectionView.contentOffset.y
            stickyAttributes.frame = frame
            stickyAttributes.zIndex = 9
            stickyAttributes.isHidden = false
            
            return stickyAttributes
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

if there is no section with orthgonalScrollingBehavior in collectionView, it works perfectly
but with orthgonalScrollingBehavior, the sticky cell disappears when scrolled.

Is there any solution?

tried customizing UICollectionViewLayout